Why is に connected to a verb? I thought it could only attach to nouns or is it because it a “double particle”?

Why is に attached to 終わる？　if it’s 終わり then I would’ve known but why is it there? Is it because there’s a は next to it, the so called “double particle”? Are these “double particles” an exception to the rule?

This already has an answer. Here's how you might look something like this up: search for "[particle-に] [grammar] に dictionary form verb". https://japanese.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bparticle-%E3%81%AB%5D+%5Bgrammar%5D+%E3%81%AB+dictionary+form+verb

(If the top answer in those results somehow doesn't satisfy you, make a comment over there to ask for clarification or discuss whatever point/detail you might be wondering about. If it's major enough, make a new, more specific question.)

This pattern is explained here:

Dictionary form of verb followed by に

The dictionary form (or more precisely, the attributive form) of a verb worked as a noun in the past, and that's why a combination like 終わるに, without an explicit nominalizer, is still found in some patterns. See my answer here: Plain Verb followed by がよい

So technically if any of the particles are after an attributive form of a verb, they are still correct in the eyes of old Japanese but in modern Japanese that’s wrong and should have a の or こと before the particles

@JackyPlays That's an oversimplification, and there are times where attributive-form + particle will look perfectly normal. There's nothing old in the sentence in question.

so I just have to look ai it scenario by scenario
