Just what is the difference between 連用形 and 連体形？
I know that 終止形 means that the verb at the end of a sentence is done. It’s at its end and that why it’s called 終止 in the first place but just what are the differences between 連用形 and 連体形. When the 終止形 of the verb get thrown in front of the noun, then it becomes modifier for that word but is that then called 連用形 or 連体形 cause to me it seems like they are the same thing. Just what is the difference between them?

Your question seems to have a few wrinkles to it in how best to answer.  
The shapes of the words
In modern Japanese, the shape / form / pronunciation of the 連体形【れんたいけい】 ("adnominal form") and the 終止形【しゅうしけい】 ("terminal / predicative form") are identical for (almost) all verbs and -i adjectives.  (There are a few exceptions, such as the copular "to be" verb だ.)
However, in classical and Old Japanese, the adnominal and terminal forms were different for -i adjectives and for non-type-1 verbs.

For verbs, this includes things like modern 食べる【たべる】 ("to eat").  In classical and Old Japanese, this had the terminal form of たぶ, and the adnominal form of たぶる.
The adnominal was also used to end sentences in certain styles and grammatical situations, and this may have been part of why the adnominal form began to replace the terminal form, with the medial "u" vowel in the adnominal also shifting to match the "e" vowel of the verb's other conjugated forms.  We see this most clearly in texts from the Muromachi period in the 1400s and 1500s (if my memory is correct).

For -i adjectives, the classical and Old Japanese terminal forms ended in し, and the adnominal ended in き.  So modern 高い【たかい】 was 高し【たかし】 in the terminal form (the etymological source of the masculine given name "Takashi"), and 高き【たかき】 in the adnominal form.  Similarly, modern よい was either よし (which you'll probably still hear sometimes) at the end of a sentence, or よき before a noun.
Around the same time that verbs were shifting, adjectives also underwent changes, where the adnominal replaced the terminal.  There was also a loss of the "k" sound in き, giving us modern 高い【たかい】 and よい.


The functions of these conjugations
You're correct about the 終止形【しゅうしけい】: this is the form (形【けい】) that ends/stops (終止【しゅうし】) a statement or clause.
The names of the other two forms you ask about similarly give us some useful information.

The 連用形【れんようけい】 is the form (形【けい】) that connects to (連【れん】) another inflecting word (用言【ようげん】).  This might be another verb or verb auxiliary (a kind of suffix that also inflects/conjugates), or it might serve as a kind of adverb or adverbial phrase, modifying another verb or verbal phrase.  In Japanese grammars, this is why the adverbial form of an adjective, like 高く【たかく】 or よく, is said to be in the 連用形【れんようけい】.  English-language sources have various names for this form, including "continuative, continuing, adverbial, gerundive, -masu stem", among others.
The 連体形【れんたいけい】 is the form (形【けい】) that connects to (連【れん】) a non-inflecting word (体言【たいげん】) — generally, a noun or noun phrase.

Modern differences in the forms
For most verbs and for the -i adjectives, the 終止形【しゅうしけい】 and 連体形【れんたいけい】 are the same thing anymore.  However, for the -na adjectives and a small handful of verbs, these are still different.  Consider the copular verb だ: this is the terminal form.  The adnominal form appears most obviously with -na adjectives: 静か【しずか】だ is the terminal, but 静か【しずか】な is the adnominal form that you need when using this adjective to directly modify a noun or noun phrase.
Another oddball is the verb 得る【える】 ("to get; to be ~-able").  This can also be used as an auxiliary, basically as a suffixing element on another verb to make a kind of potential "this [VERB] can happen" statement.  One place you might hear it from time to time is in the word ありえる, literally "be-able", expressing that something might exist or might be possible.  ありえる is technically the terminal form, and some speakers still default to using the older classical adnominal form ありうる when using this verb to directly modify a noun or noun phrase.

I hope that gives you a workable background.  If this doesn't fully address your question, please comment and I can update as needed.

Follow-on questions

So basically 連用形 is the いstem that websites say and its usage is to put it behind a verb or an いadjective to modify it, then does that word with なadjectives?

The 連用形【れんようけい】 is also called the "-masu stem" in some English-language resources.  This is the verb conjugation form used when forming a compound verb (like in Karl's 飛び【とび】込む【こむ】 example, where 飛び【とび】 is the verb 飛ぶ【とぶ】 in this conjugation), or when adding an auxiliary like the polite indicator ～ます.
However, you cannot use the 連用形 conjugation of a verb to modify an -i adjective — in fact, I don't think you can use a verb to modify an adjective in any conjugation.  Instead, you use the 連用形 conjugation of an adjective to turn it into an adverb, which you can then use to modify a verb.
The corresponding 連用形 for -na adjectives is the adverbial particle に.  Compare:

動く【うごく】車【くるま】は静か【しずか】だ。
"The moving car is quiet."
→ The だ is in the 終止形【しゅうしけい】 or terminal form, since it is being used to terminate a sentence.
静か【しずか】な車【くるま】は動く【うごく】。
"The quiet car moves."
→ The な is in the 連体形【れんたいけい】 or adnominal / attributive form, since it is being used to modify a following noun or noun phrase.
車【くるま】は静か【しずか】に動く【うごく】。
"The car moves quietly."
→ The に is in the 連用形【れんようけい】 or continuative / adverbial form, since it is being used to modify a following verb or verb phrase.


And the 連体形 is basically the dictionary form or the form that you would use to end a sentence with thats usage is to modify a noun.

In terms of the shape of modern verbs, the 連体形【れんたいけい】 and 終止形【しゅうしけい】 are the same for most verbs.  However, note the names:

連体形【れんたいけい】 = the form (形【けい】) that connects to (連【れん】) a non-inflecting word (体言【たいげん】) — a noun or noun phrase.  This is also called the adnominal or attributive form.
終止形【しゅうしけい】 = the form (形【けい】) that ends/stops (終止【しゅうし】) a statement or clause.  This is also called the terminal or conclusive or predicative form.

It's the 終止形【しゅうしけい】 that's the dictionary form.  This just happens to be the same shape as the 連体形【れんたいけい】 for most verbs in the modern language.
I think Karl's response in the comments addresses your other question.
Cheers!

So basically 連用形 is the いstem that websites say and its usage is to put it behind a verb or an いadjective to modify it, then does that word with なadjectives? And the 連体形 is basically the dictionary form or the form that you would use to end a sentence with thats usage is to modify a noun.

I would like to ask a thing, I’ve seen some post that says you can put particles on 連体形, without the normalising の　and こと、 and they say it’s because in the past, 連体形 were considered as “nouns” and the whole concept of normalising wasn’t even a thing, so even in today’s Japanese grammar standards, is it still considered correct that you don’t have to put a こと or の after a 連体形 or people just use it to sound fancy？

"so even in today’s Japanese grammar standards, is it still considered correct that you don’t have to put a こと or の after a 連体形 or people just use it to sound fancy？" I guess you're talking about your own question https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/106334, or the one that naruto linked you to from there. If you aren't making this kind of poetic reference (maybe I should say, following a set pattern), better use a nominalizer. (There are more choices besides こと and の depending on the context.)

Your comment about ありえる is somehow misleading. Classical terminal form was ありう, and classical adnominal form was ありうる. ありえる is both terminal and adnominal form after shifting this word from nidan class to ichidan class.

@Arfrever, apologies if my wording was confusing -- ありえる is the modern terminal, and is both the classical adnominal and still the modern adnominal, depending on speaker.  I've encountered both ありえる and ありうる in the adnominal role, and looking online right now, it looks like ありうる is more common.

@EiríkrÚtlendi Classically, this verb / verbal suffix was in nidan class, so like all other verbs in nidan class, its 終止形 and 連体形 must have ended with -u and -uru respectively.

Also there was no shimo ichidan class in Old Japanese, while in Early Middle Japanese (Classical Japanese) shimo ichidan class appeared and had only 1 verb: kweru (stem kwe-) (which was kuwe- in shimo nidan class in Old Japanese). (Later, this verb migrated to godan class.)

@Arfrever, yes, but why are you bringing that up?  ありえる in modern usage is an irregular reflection of classical conjugation patterns.  — Ah, I see that I garbled things in my previous comment post in the course of composing my reply.  (I wish those were editable after more than 5 minutes...).  ありえる is 1) the modern terminal, and 2) the modern adnominal for some speakers, while other speakers (apparently more commonly) use the ありうる form as the adnominal. Meanwhile, ありう (the classical terminal) seldom appears anymore, unless someone is being deliberately archaic.

superuseful point on ありえる/ありうる, I was aware there are two pronunciations for that verb but didn't understand their nuances.

Shorter version:
First, we can understand which is which by considering the core meanings of the individual kanji.
連体形 -> connect-object-form. It's what you put in front of an object (i.e., a noun) to connect some predicate phrase to it so that it modifies the meaning. In other words, the attributive (as Jisho glosses it) or adnominal (as Eirikr does) form.
連用形 -> connect-utilize-form. This is the form you use with a verb or an adjective - a utilize-word (用言), a word that expresses a function. That's an i-stem (masu-stem) for verbs, as in compounds like [飛]{と}び[込]{こ}む, and a く ending for i-adjectives, as in よろしくおねがいします.
It's hard to speak meaningfully of "differences", because they're not related, aside from both being inflections of a verb. It's worth noting that the core concepts of 体 and 用 are commonly opposed to each other; see the word 体用 expressing the dichotomy.
Then, to address the cause of confusion:

When the 終止形 of the verb get thrown in front of the noun, then it becomes modifier for that word but is that then called 連用形 or 連体形

It must be 連体形, by the above analysis. But pedantically, it's not just the 終止形 "being called" 連体形; it's a separate inflection - it's just that, in modern Japanese, it has the same sound and appearance as the 終止形 in almost every case. The most notable exception is the informal copula だ, which becomes な in 連体形. (This is the な of so-called "na-adjectives".)
(Additional confusion may appear if you have to deal with archaic expressions or poetry. Eirikr gives an overview of the history.)
